# Check Object Type

Tags: javascript

I have a function which returns an object, and it generally is one of the two:

[image]

How can I differentiate between the object being of type `DraftEditor` or the other one in the screenshot above?

Running `typeOf(myVar)` returns `'Object'` in both cases.

Comment: [`instanceof`](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof)?

Comment: @deceze I can't use that unless I can supply the DraftEditor object as a parameter, which I can't because it's supplied by a package which doesn't give me access to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `instanceof` operator to check object for being of given type. Check this article on it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof

Comment: How can I retrieve the `DraftEditor` object so that I can perform the comparison? Using a `DraftEditor` string doesn't work because it's not an object.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike some have suggested, I cannot use `instanceof` because I don't have access to the `DraftEditor` object (it's sourced from an [external package](https://github.com/jpuri/react-draft-wysiwyg)).

Instead, I used the following:

```
ref.constructor.name === 'DraftEditor'
```